# kubectl create deployment --image=<image name>,

Tags: kubectl

Question:

I am trying to use the `kubectl create deployment` command with the `--image` flag to create a deployment with an image from a specific location. However, I am confused about where to find the right image name. Should it be from Docker Image Hub or from Google's `gcr.io`? Can someone explain how to determine the correct image name and its location?

For example, I would like to create a deployment with the `nginx:v1` image. Is this from Docker Image Hub or `gcr.io`? How do I determine the correct image names and their locations?

```
kubectl create deployment --image=nginx:v1
```

```
kubectl create deployment --image=alpine:latest
```

Comment: Generally you'll want to go to the owner e.g. NGINX's home page to find the definitive location (registry) of software including container images. You can use your preferred search engine to find e.g. `dockerhub nginx` and `dockerhub alpine` and note that dockerhub often contains "Official Image" e.g. [NGINX](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) and [Alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine). Somewhat confusingly, this means that you will then need to use `docker.io/nginx` (not `hub.docker.com`) to access the image.

Comment: Google Container Registry (`gcr.io`), Quay (`quay.io`) and other container registries provide their own sets of container images and often mirror (provide copies) of images **but** it's the user responsibility to ensure any container image is legitimate and then's nothing to stop e.g. `badactor.io/nginx` from being published too.

Comment: If a registry or repository requires authentication, you will need to provide the credentials to Kubernetes as you would if you were to use e.g. Docker or Podman to pull the container yourself. Authentication ([Pulling an Image from a Private Registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)) is a common cause of deployment issues (of images) to Kubernetes.